# How to remove element on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add elements to container on a first click and delete it on a second one. I guess I'm trying to make it super hard while there is a more elegant and clear solution. [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Mundiscode/p8hmt601/49/)

I was thinking of arrays to create a 1st array for clicked elements and the 2nd one for elements that are already in a container. Then filter the first array through the second one and delete those (unmatched) elements from my container.

```
var click = +$(this).data('clicks') || 0; // Check if contacts cliked first time
if (click % 2 == 1) { // 2nd click
  fruits.splice($.inArray(name, fruits), 1); // Remove Name from an array
  $(".test .single").each(function (index, elem) {
    compArr.push($(this).text());
  });
  keyArr = fruits.filter(i => compArr.indexOf(i) !== -1);
  var i = 0;
  for (; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
    $(".name").each(function () {
      $(".single:not(:contains('" + keyArr + "'))").remove();
    });
  } // I guess problem is here
} else { // 1st click
  fruits.push(name);
  $('.test textarea').css({
    'font-size': '12px',
    'border': '0'
  }).prop('placeholder', '').before('<span class="single">' + name + '></span>');
  $('textarea').val('');
}

$(this).data('clicks', click + 1);
```

For me, this part doesn't work properly. But I would love to hear any of your suggestions even if the entire logic is wrong. Thanks!

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
  $(".name").each(function () {
    $(".single:not(:contains('" + keyArr + "'))").remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: why don't u add an attribute to each <div> of Apple,Berry and then try to directly traverse the DOM and find if they already exist then remove else add them?

Comment: Hey Hitesh, thanks for your reply. First of all, Apple, Berry, and other fruits will be jQuery elements that are added dynamically by user. Secondly, I don't need to delete those elements but span elements with .single class that contains the same text as those Apple, Berry, and so on. Thanks! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it. Added this code:

```
let deleteSingle = $('.single');
for (let i = 0; i < deleteSingle.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arrayNewKeys.length; j++) {
    if (deleteSingle[i].innerHTML.includes(arrayNewKeys[j])) {
      deleteSingle.eq(i).addClass('a');
      break;
    } else {
      deleteSingle.eq(i).removeClass('a');
    }
  }
}
$('.styleContacts:not(.a)').remove();
if ($('.test > .single.a:only-child')) {
  $('.single.a').removeClass('a');
}
```

Instead of this:

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
  $(".name").each(function () {
    $(".single:not(:contains('" + keyArr + "'))").remove();
  });
} // I guess problem is here
```